# How to get the system HTTP proxy configuration in Java

Tags: java, networking, proxy

Is it possible to get the system proxy configuration in Java?

In the Java Control Panel, you can set a proxy configuration. How can I access to that proxy configuration in order to open URL connections behind a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh, just look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376101/setting-jvm-jre-to-use-windows-proxy-automatically) question.
there was a sample with a solution.

currently all samples I've seen use SUN's undocumented APIs (com.sum packages), which result in warnings at compile time...

Answer (score 1):

The Java Plugin gets it from the system settings. If the app has to be started as either applet or webstart you can use the webstart/applet APIs for this. Otherwise you have to use native code. Look at the various JniWrapper's WinPack and the JDIC libs - they might have done the heavy lifting for you.