# Why is ProxySelector returning inconsistent results in Java?

Tags: java, networking, proxy, proxyselector

8 months ago I used this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376101/setting-jvm-jre-to-use-windows-proxy-automatically) to automatically use a proxy server in a Java project.  It worked beautifully.

Here is the code I came up with at the time:

```
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    List<Proxy> proxyServers = null;
    try {
        proxyServers = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://www.twitter.com"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      System.out.println("Error using system proxy");
    }
    if (proxyServers != null) {
        for (Iterator<Proxy> iter = proxyServers.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Proxy proxy = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Found Proxy: " + proxy);
            InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();

            if (addr == null) {
              System.out.println("No Proxy");
            } else {

                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));

                System.out.println("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName());
                System.out.println("proxy port : " + addr.getPort());

            }
        }
    }
```

I tried adding this exact same code to another project recently and I get different results.  I have my computer setup to use a test proxy server and ran both projects to compare the results.  If I run the project from 8 months ago the following is printed out:

```
Found Proxy: HTTP @ 192.168.1.100:8000
proxy hostname : 192.168.1.100
proxy port : 8000
```

If I run my current project on the same machine with the same Proxy server set up, the following is printed out.

```
Found Proxy: DIRECT 
No Proxy
```

The only proxy found is a "Direct" and proxy.address() is null.

What would cause this to find the proxy settings in one case but not the other?

**Edit:**

I fixed this, by moving the code sooner in the startup process, but I don't know why this fixed it.

Comment: How do run it? Eclipse, jar, smth else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably due to this sentence in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies

> java.net.useSystemProxies (default: false) On recent Windows systems
>   and on Gnome 2.x systems it is possible to tell the java.net stack,
>   setting this property to true, to use the system proxy settings
>   (both these systems let you set proxies globally through their user
>   interface). **Note that this property is checked only once at startup.**

You can guarantee it working if you put the property in the java command: `java -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true yourclass`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the code along with secure page, it will not consider the proxy hence it would display Direct and No Proxy.

Try the below code:

```
proxyServers = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://www.twitter.com"));
proxyServers = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("https://www.twitter.com"));
```

you will get the difference.