# Applying the system settings of SOCKS proxy in Java, programmatically

Tags: java, proxy

I need to apply all proxy system settings in my Java program.

It needs to happen in certain conditions so **I can't use the JVM argument** method (-D).

I'm using the accepted answer from [Setting JVM/JRE to use Windows Proxy Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376101/setting-jvm-jre-to-use-windows-proxy-automatically)
and it works for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP.

But it simply won't work for SOCKS.

How can I detect SOCKS settings from the OS?
Alternatively, how can I can apply all OS proxy settings blindly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
The protocol label for HTTP is "HTTP".

HTTPS: "HTTPS"

FTP: "FTP"

SOCKS? "SOCKET"